# Is there a "tab control" Control for PowerBi

Tags: powerbi, tabcontrol, linechart

Is there a Tab Control control in Power Bi that can be dropped onto a dashboard similar to other controls, like checkbox, list, etc. I would like the user to be able to add various inputs on each tab and then be able to plot a line on a chart based on their selections. Each tab on the Tab control would represent a separate product. An image of a tab control can be found at the link below.

[image: Tab Control]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if Power BI has something like that out of the box, but you could roll your own.

It looks like you want a bunch of slicers that are overlapping and come to the top when their "tab" is clicked. You can achieve this by showing/hiding slicers when a button is clicked. Conceptually:

- add slicers to the report and arrange to overlap
- add buttons to the report and arrange side by side
- add bookmarks to the page that show the different hidden/visible states of the slicers
- assign the bookmarks to the buttons

Matt Allington has a [blog post](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/create-a-power-bi-slicer-panel/) about this technique. He uses just one slicer panel, so you will need to adjust it to your needs but it has everything you need to do what you describe.